# laravel query - use multiple condition constraints between two related tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I'm newbie to Laravel. I have a problem for my project. Similarly, I have 2 structure tables as follows:

```
cases (id, name, customer_id, abc, xyz)
case_employees (id, case_id, employee_id, customer_id)
employees (id, name)
```

Relationship between tables:

```
$case->hasMany(CaseEmployee::class, 'case_id');
$case_employee->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'employee_id');
```

My query is as follows:

```
Case::with(['case_employees' => function($query) {
            $query->with('employee:id,name')
                ->where(['cases.customer_id', '=', 'case_employees.customer_id'])
                ->first();
        }])->get();
```

My problem is something like this: *->where(['cases.customer_id', '=', 'case_employees.customer_id'])*.
That is, get the list of cases with case_employees, with employee (extra condition: cases.customer_id = case_employees.customer_id).

I want to get:

```
$cases = [
    id: 123,
    name: 'abc',
    customer_id: 234,
    case_employees: [
        id: 1,
        case_id: 123,
        employee_id: 2,
        customer_id: 234,
        employee: [
            id: 2,
            name: 'def',
        ]
    ],
    case_employees: [
        id: 2,
        case_id: 123,
        employee_id: 3,
        customer_id: 234,
        employee: [
            id: 3,
            name: 'xyz',
        ]
    ],
]
```

Can someone help me with a correct query? You can use DB::query() as well.

In addition to passing foreign keys, I want to check more conditions between the 2 tables. For example customer_id on cases and customer_id on case_employees.

Comment: simply say what you want to get.?

Comment: @hasan05 I've updated my question

Comment: $cases = [
    id: 123,
    name: 'abc',
    customer_id: 234,
    case_employees: [
        id: 1,
        case_id: 123,
        employee_id: 2,
        customer_id: 234,
        employee: [
            id: 2,
            name: 'def',
        ],
        id: 2,
        case_id: 123,
        employee_id: 3,
        customer_id: 234,
        employee: [
            id: 3,
            name: 'xyz',
        ]
    ],
]

Will this helpfull to you?

screenshot: https://prnt.sc/rir5fw

Comment: I can't see the screenshot. It seems that it is not available to me

Comment: sorry, you have to go to the link on *prnt.sc*

Comment: Yes, I did, but it looks like this: https://prnt.sc/ris66t

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what I understood from you description, you want all employees for every cases with employee detail.

call it by,

```
Case::with('case_employees', 'case_employees.employee')->get();
```

It will return all cases with eagerloaded employee array where every employee will get eager loaded detail object.

Comment: In addition to passing foreign keys, I want to check more conditions between the 2 tables. For example customer_id on cases and customer_id on case_employees.

Comment: My personal opinion, you dont need `customer_id` in `case_employees` hense one `case` has many `case_employees`. Rather then you can add conditions by `whereHas`   https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence